# Playframework User Actor with User Session

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

I'm pretty new to Scala, the Play Framework and Akka. In the project I currently work on, the user of the web application should be able to ask the server several things to do (like starting a particular computation) in an asynchronous way. If the server is done it should notify the user also async. I solve this demand by a **WebSocket** connection which is established when the user first connects with the Application and the WebSocket is handled by a `UserActor`, which is attached to the User Session:

```
def ws = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { implicit request =>

    Future.successful(request.session.get(UID) match {
        case None => Left(Forbidden)
        case Some(uid) => Logger.info("WebSocket has accepted the request with uid " + uid)
                          Right(UserActor.props(uid))
    })
}
```

Currently, the only thing the **UserActor** does is receiving messages from the `WebSocket` as `JsValue`. The UID of the session is generated when requesting index:

```
def index = Action { implicit request => {
    val uid = request.session.get(UID).getOrElse {
      counter += 1
      counter.toString
    }
    Ok(views.html.index(uid)).withSession {
      Logger.debug("create uid " + uid)
      request.session + (UID -> uid)
    }}
}
```

The `UserActor` should represent the actual user on the Server and thus include the logic of all actions that the user can perform on the Server. This works fine as long as I send all user interaction over the `WebSocket`.

Now what is the case with other user input, like form submission? The application includes a form whose data should not go over the `WebSocket`, but rather be submitted with a `POST` request (perhaps with AJAX) and bound in a controller to the Model like described in the documentation.

```
def saveContact = Action { implicit request =>
  contactForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest(views.html.contact.form(formWithErrors))
    },
    contact => {
      val contactId = Contact.save(contact)
      Redirect(routes.Application.showContact(contactId)).flashing("success" -> "Contact saved!")
    }
  )
}
```

This example is taken from the [Playframework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms).

Now, how do I link the Form Submission handler with the `UserActor`? Say I want to tell the user actor that a form has been submitted. A trivial example would be that the `UserActor` sends one value of the form back over the `WebSocket` to the client as soon it is received. So basically the problem reduces to the issue that I want to send the `UserActor` Messages from any `Controller`.

I might come up with the idea to send all form data over the WebSocket, but I also want to realize the upload of large data in the future, which I want to tackle like described [in this blog post](http://kongaraju.blogspot.in/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html). Then one scenario I could imagine is that the `UserActor` should be messaged for each chunk it receives.

I guess one problem is that the `UserActor` and the `WebSocketActor` are the same and I rather should split their logic, such that the `UserActor` is only associated with the Session, but I have no idea how to accomplish this. Maybe I need another actor, say a `UserManager`, which keeps track of present `UserActors` and enables access to `UserActors`?

Do you have any suggestions, recommendations or perhaps an example application which also deals with this case? Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the actor that you pass to `tryAcceptWithActor` as a representation of the `User`. It should represent a *particular* session with that user. Possibly, one of many concurrent sessions (multiple browsers, or tabs) a user could have open at a particular time.

Create a separate actor to represent the user and all of the actions it can perform. Now the session actors should forward their messages to the user actor. Traditional controller methods can also forward requests to the corresponding user actors.